# :assets group gems being used in environments other than development and test

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, bundler

With the below code in my application, when I run the bundle command

```
bundle install --without development:test
```

the gems in the :assets group are still being used, even though I specified that the :assets group should only be used for development or test environment.

```
# application.rb
if defined?(Bundler)
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
end

# Gemfile
group :assets do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem "turbo-sprockets-rails3", "~> 0.2"
end
```

Comment: try deleting the gemfile.lock and rebundle it and see.

Comment: I did just now, then tried bundle install --without development:test and same outcome

Comment: Using group :development,:test works fine but I'd like to know why the above is not working,